# Wordpress site header moving behind page elements on scroll

Tags: css, wordpress

On the wordpress site I have built ([www.theblackseeds.com/home](http://www.theblackseeds.com/home/)), the whole site-header sometimes becomes static/sticky with the page elements scrolling over the top/behind it when scrolling down. It also moves slightly to the right. It should just scroll as normal with the rest of the page.

It does not seem to happen in Chrome on Mac.
It does seem to happen all the time in Safari (9.1.3) on Mac.
It does seem to usually happen in Firefox on Mac, only if the user scrolls down before the whole page has loaded. If the page has completely loaded it scrolls as normal as it should.

I am stumped, any ideas? I've tried changing the position element on the site-header div, the z-index, adding a height, nothing seems to have helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you scroll down on the page the `masthead-fixed` class is getting applied to the `body` tag.

You can either find out why that's happening (it's somewhere in the Javascript) and stop that, or declare some CSS overrides:

```css
.masthead-fixed .site-main {
    margin-top: auto !important;
}

.masthead-fixed .site-header {
    position: static !important;
}
```

Comment: i've been looking at it too, same conclusion. the theme is twentyfourteen, does this still get updates?   the problem happens here: http://www.theblackseeds.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/js/functions.js   look for "body.addClass( 'masthead-fixed' );"  with @Mark suggestion, you will lose the fixed header on small screen for all browsers.  you will have to figure out why this function is not working for safari.

Comment: Thank you both Mark and Beatroot. It is a pretty old site now, had only just been made aware of the issue. It seems that CSS fixed it all good so thank you very much!